# Solving relativistic free EOM

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, spacetime

Consider a relativistic free particle of rest mass $m$. From Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, it's Lagrangian is $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}mV^{\mu}V_{\mu},$$ where $V^{\mu}=\frac{\mathrm{d} x^{\mu}}{\mathrm{d} \tau}$ are the components of the four velocity., and Einstein summation convention is used. Using the Euler-Lagrange equation in the form $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \tau} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial V^{\mu}}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^{\mu}},$$ and after some rearrangements, one gets the equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x^{\mu}}{\mathrm{d} \tau ^2}=0$. My question is: how can this equation be solved? My guess is that I have to integrate twice in order to get $ct(\tau)=t_0+k\tau$, for the time coordinate and $x(\tau)=x_0+u\tau$, where $t_0$, $k$, $x_0$, and $u$ are constants that depend on the initial conditions, and similarly for the $y$ and $z$ coordinates. Is this right, or I'm missing something?